# Laptop with a 17" screen which can take a 15.5mm 4tB hgarddrive

Tags: laptop, hard-disk

That's all.

For those who don't know, they get larger capacity by adding more platters to the drive. That makes it physically taller than normal, and most laptops won't accommodate such a drive.

I don't care at all about graphics. I prefer 16gB RAM, but can add that myself. I don't particalarly care abour processor, although Core i5 (or above) or AMD equavalent would be nice.

Just screen size & the cance to whack in a big, in both senses, harddrive.

UK based, or cheap postage thereto a bonus. Lower price is, of course, welcome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most laptops ship with a 2.5" Hard drive (usually 1 tB) pre-installed into the system. If you're willing to remove it and replace it with your own 4tB drive, I think pretty much any system would meet your requirements.

Comment: And you would be 100% wrong. The vast majority of laptops take 7.5mm, 9mm or 11mm drives.  I have been checking specs for over a week now, and cannot find one capable of taking a 15.5mm 4tB drive (e.g https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/hdd/barracuda/#specs-2-5).

Comment: I added a bit to the question, explaining the physical difference between 4tb and normal laptop drives

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had a brain fart there. In general you're not going to find a laptop that is going to take a hard drive that massive, or at least it would be one fat laptop. You're best bet is probably going to be to go for an [external enclosure. Here's one that supports 15 mm 2.5 hard drives](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707415).

Comment: Sorry, but I won't go external. I am thinking maybe something designated as a gaming laptop?

Comment: Seems they only go up to 9.5 mm height. I found a few laptops supporting a 4 TB hard drive, but they weren't 15 mm in stature. I'm pretty sure your hard disk was intended for server racks, etc.

Comment: I suspect that you are correct :-( I remember when 9mm was standard & they squeezed in a few platters to take 1tB to 2tB. It was the same story then, when it required 11mm and almost all laptops only accepted 9mm :-(

Comment: You can get 4TB in a 17" laptop if you don't mind the fact that there will be more than one drive, e.g. 2 x 2 GB 7 mm 2.5 drives. I have seen even 15" laptops with up to four drive bays from Dell, Lenovo, etc.